# TFS Server plugin fails after upgrade from TFS2012 to TFS2015 RC

Tags: plugins, tfs-2015

We have just upgraded one of our servers from TFS2012.2 to TFS2015RC. Everything went "smooth", but we are encountering an issue:

A while ago we wrote a server side plugin for TFS, which listens to the `WorkitemChangedEvent`. It implements the `ISubscriber` interface. The following piece of code was working fine before the update:

```
void ITfsService.UpdateState(int workItemId, string newState)
{
    var wi = store.GetWorkItem(workItemId);
    wi.State = newState;
    wi.Save();               
}
```

After the update, and after recompiling against the TFS2015 dlls, the following error occured:

> Failed to process notification: TF237124: Work Item is not ready to save.

Note that none of the workitemtypes has changed, it is the same data.
I tried getting more information out of the error by calling `Validate()` before saving, this is the output:

> Status: InvalidListValue
>   State: "Resolved, To Be Reviewed"
>   WIT: Task
>   Id: 5842
>   Field: State

However, the state "Resolved, To Be Reviewed" does exists in the list of available states. In the GUI it is perfectly possible to change the state of the item to "Resolved, To Be Reviewed":

[image: screenshot saving state in GUI]

What is causing the Save() to fail?

Comment: The data warehouse is updated?

Comment: how do I know if it was upgraded? I didn't explicitely do that, just let the TFS upgrade process take care of it...

Comment: In the object model you can also list all possible states of a witd. What does the object model mention as valid values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the cause of this:
Apparently, the `Validate()` call validates against the whole `ProcessConfiguration.xml`. Because in TFS2012 there were both `AgileProcessConfiguration` and `CommonProcessConfiguration`, there were underlying problems with the workitem states.

After resolving those issues in the correct `ProcessConfiguration` file, the plugin was working again (and, TFS could also upgrade the Backlog\IterationPlanning features.)